Why when I run firefox browser it takes a lot of memory?
On Kubuntu 22.04 sometimes when I run the Firefox browser I see it takes a lot of memory and my OS becomes very slow.
Sometimes it hangs up the system. I check with the top command  and see this. :
      63 root      20   0       0      0      0 R  73,9   0,0   0:26.99 kswapd0                                                                                                                                                                                                
  19765 master    20   0   11,6g 237964   8744 R  52,2   3,0   0:15.20 firefox                                                                                                                                                                                                
  18164 master    20   0   32,5g  30468   7700 R  47,8   0,4   0:09.27 skypeforlinux                                                                                                                                                                                          
  18978 root      20   0       0      0      0 D  21,7   0,0   0:01.14 kworker/u8:4+loop20                                                                                                                                                                                    
    752 root      20   0  106284  94860    640 S  13,0   1,2   4:58.19 mount.ntfs-3g                                                                                                                                                                                          
   8163 master    20   0   21,3g 173424   3840 R  13,0   2,2   3:40.09 node          

I searched and found some proposals to explain/solve this problem.
like
https://community.toradex.com/t/kswapd0-hogging-cpu-freezing-device/20467
Which settings can I try to use to solve the issue? Why so much memory is used by Firefox and kswapd0 services ?
uname -a
Linux master-at-home 6.5.0-35-generic #35~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Tue May  7 09:00:52 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

free
               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:         8040236     5871204      577576      582876     1591456     1295780
Swap:        2104476     2101828        2648

